# How to make Pixaria work without ini_set()?

Tags: security, php, webserver, vulnerabilities

I am working on a server which has Pixaria installed. After wasting (yes, completely wasted) hours trying to find out why it showed a blank page, I finally decided to try to enable ini_set() in php.ini and what do you know, voila it showed up (the page worked, after saving and restarting apache so php.ini changes could take effect).

However, I DO NOT want ini_set on! ***Especially*** because there is a **security hole in Pixaria** which using ini_set a hacker can gain access to your server.

So how can I make Pixaria work, **without** having ini_set enabled?

Comment: did you find any solution?